# The indexOf method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexof

I'm trying to understand a lot of the basic components of Javascript and one of the things I came across is a line of code saying

```
if (varX.indexOf(String(varY),0) < 0)
```

varX being an array of Strings and varY being obviously one of the strings within that array. Take away the ",0" and I understand that the code is just looking for varY withing array varX. But I don't know what the ,0 does and what means for the if statement. I did what I could to look this up and didn't really come across anything.

Comment: The `,0` denotes the start of the search. It default starts at 0, so this is redundant.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf - where have you looked it up?

Comment: I was doing some google searches but I guess the way I was searching it wasn't really the best way. Now that I look back, I sort of how I didn't find it in my searches. Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> ```
> fromindex
> ```
>
> The index to start the search at. If the index is greater than or equal to the array's length, -1 is returned, which means the array will not be searched. If the provided index value is a negative number, it is taken as the offset from the end of the array. Note: if the provided index is negative, the array is still searched from front to back. If the calculated index is less than 0, then the whole array will be searched. Default: 0 (Entire array is searched).

So, passing in "0" is pretty much pointless, as it starts off the search at 0 anyway.

Comment: It should be noted that there's no good reason for doing it the way it is in the code example provided, since 0 is the default.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would give an upvote but I apparently need 15 rep to do that and I don't have that yet. Gave a check though! :)

Answer (score 2):

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> ```
> arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = 0])
>
> fromIndex
> ```
>
> The index to start the search at. If the index is greater than or
>   equal to the array's length, -1 is returned, which means the array
>   will not be searched. If the provided index value is a negative
>   number, it is taken as the offset from the end of the array. Note: if
>   the provided index is negative, the array is still searched from front
>   to back. If the calculated index is less than 0, then the whole array
>   will be searched. Default: 0 (Entire array is searched).

Answer (score 0):

`0` is index from where you start the search. It is `0` by default, so you don't have to pass this parameter.